# Check if it has online connection

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a small function to see if the android running my app has Online Connection.

I already tried to run it, but I'm getting an error on this line:

```
NetworkInfo [] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
```

Here's my code (button just to make a small message saying if I'm connected to the internet or not)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ConnectionDetector Connection = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            boolean hasConnection = Connection.isConnectionToInternet();
            if(hasConnection) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Está ligado à internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não está ligado à internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
                }
        });
```

ConnectionDetector Class

```
package com.example.testlayout.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context context ;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this.context = context ;
    }

    public boolean isConnectionToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(connectivity != null )
        {

            NetworkInfo [] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();

            if(info != null)
                for(int i = 0 ; i < info.length ;i++)
                    if(info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true ;
                    }
        }
        return false ;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
04-10 16:15:35.597  26543-26543/com.example.testlayout.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testlayout.app, PID: 26543
    java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10117 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getAllNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:881)
            at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:620)
            at com.example.testlayout.app.ConnectionDetector.isConnectionToInternet(ConnectionDetector.java:22)
            at com.example.testlayout.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Neither user 10117 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. Do you need more hints? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't crashes, but I can't see the toast, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, add .show() to your Toast call like this: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Está ligado à internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't add `uses-permission` to access network state that's why its throwing the `Exception`...

```
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10117 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

Now, add this permission in your `Manifest` file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Also add following permission if you want to know wifi network state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```